# prevent styles from applying by cascade when using LESS nested rules

Tags: html, css, less

We're developing a large plugin based front-end system and trying to figure out how to compose CSS rules. Basically there are two ways:

1. Specify parents in the class name
2. Specify parents in the selector (by using LESS nested rules)

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<div class="dashboard">
   <span class="dashboard__title"></span>
   <div class="custom-widget">
        <span class="dashboard__custom-widget__title"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

And for second approach:

```
<div class="dashboard">
   <span class="title"></span>
   <div class="custom-widget">
        <span class="title"></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to specify specific style for `.title` inside `.dashboard`, so using the first approach CSS will look like that:

```
.dashboard__title {
    //styles here
}
```

With the second approach CSS will look like this:

```
.dashboard .title {
    //styles here
}
```

which takes advantage of LESS nesting capabilities:

```
.dashboard {
 .title {
   //styles here
 }
}
```

We really like the second approach as it makes LESS stylesheets easy to read by collapsing rules specific to any particular element and it also allows for short style names. However, it has a problem, which is cascading - in the case at hand styles defined for `.title` inside `.dashboard` will also be applied for `.title` inside `.custom-widget`. If we use the first approach the doesn't happen.

Please advice on ways to use LESS nesting capabilities but avoid the problem described.

**EDIT**:

It seems that I've found a solution which combines two approaches:

```
.custom-widget {
  &__save-icon {
    &--active {
      padding: 777px;
      background-image : url('');
    }
  }
}
```

Produces this kind of class:

```
.custom-widget__save-icon--active
```

Comment: You can use `.dashboard >.title`. [Something like this](http://codepen.io/anpsmn/pen/azyqRY)

Comment: You need to use child selectors instead of descendant selectors.

Comment: The solution in your edit seems to be aimed at different html than you gave in the question (i.e. there was no .b-flume-widget__save-icon--active). The simplest solution to your question is, as @anpsmn (and now others) say, is to target `.title`s that are direct children of `.dashboard`

Comment: @henry, yes, different, sorry for that. Targeting direct children is not a good idea since I'll have almost all selectors written with direct child selector, but it's certainly an option

Comment: For the sake of future readers, could you reword things a bit? Not only does the answer that worked for you not apply to the question as written, but on rereading I see that you thought (think?) `.dashboard .title { … }` in CSS or LESS is different from `.dashboard { .title {…} }` in LESS. That isn't the case: they are equivalent. If they were giving you different results something else is going on

Answer (score 3):

Just choose your element by selector like below:
This style affects only for immediate children of a .dashboard element which have class .title.

```
.dashboard > .title {
    //styles here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is a bit ambiguous because there is no »do it that way« answer possible. **BUT** some reasoning will hopefully give some hints. I think the first question you should pose yourself is: will a `span.title` happen to appear in other places too, so that the style rules for it can be reused.

In this case you could start out by abstracting the style definitions like that:

```
html:

<div class="plugin dashboard">
   <span class="title">Hey There!</span>
</div>

scss:

//general rules for each title in each plugin
div.plugin {
    span.title {
    }
}

//override or specify
div.dashboard {
    span.title {
    }
}
```

This way, by adding a second class you can take advantage of cascading nature of CSS and with tools like LESS or SASS you can guarantee that the order of style rules will be preserved.

Otherwise, if you just want to make sure that your style rules only apply for elements inside the `.plugin__container`, just scope it as you did in the question and take care that the outermost »main entry point« is unique enough.

```
div.plugin-namespace {
    //all your rules here…
}
```

I hope It helped! Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, I think I've found a solution, please see my updated answer.